# Wrapping a label element within a legend element

Tags: html, label, fieldset, legend

I've never had a reason to put a label element inside of a legend element (never really thought about it or seen it done). But with the design I'm implementing, it's tempting to do so.

Here's what I'm tempted to do:

```
<fieldset>
<legend><label for="formInfo">I would like information on</label></legend>
<select id="formInfo">
    <option value="Cats">Cats</option>
    <option value="Dogs">Dogs</option>
    <option value="Lolz">Lolz</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
```

It works as expected (clicking the label focuses the corresponding input) in Firefox3, Safari, Opera, and IE6/7 and it passes validation, but I'm just wondering if there are any known reasons (accessibility? semantics? browser issues) why this shouldn't be done

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Where is your `</fieldset>`?

Semantically, [`legend` describes a `fieldset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.10), just as `label` describes a single field.

Fieldsets are supposed to be used to group together semantically related fields (for instance, an "address" fieldset might have input fields for street, city and country).

Assuming you have more than one field in the fieldset, then doing what you suggest doesn't semantically make sense -- you need to create separate legend text that describes the fieldset, then a label for each field.

If you only have one field, then you don't need fieldset or legend at all.

So, basically, you shouldn't do what you're doing.

If you're doing it to have extra elements to attach CSS rules or Javascript events to, you're better off using generic elements like `div` and `span` that won't confuse text-to-speech and other non-visual user agents.

i.e., putting in a `div` or `span` is effectively neutral in terms of accessibility/semantics (it implies nothing) versus misusing a semantic element (even if only slightly, as in this case), which is potentially misleading. Imagine even the *best-case* scenario for your layout in a text-to-speech browser: The text is read aloud twice, once as legend and once as label -- why would someone want the phrase "I would like information on" read aloud twice to them? Especially as it only makes sense in the context of the choices in the `select` control.

Comment: Voted up. RE: last paragraph - ...and if there are further fields in the fieldset then the legend will be announced for those fields too, which will probably be undesirable.

Comment: Closing FIELDSET tag got munched by the text editor. I went to add it back in, it was still there, but not in the code block.

I appreciate your reply - just the well thought out input I was hoping for. I was on the fence and you've eloquently talked me down. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, the LEGEND element is a little difficult to control with css. I was going to use absolute positioning, but ran into problems. In the end, I decided to forgo the LEGEND element and use a LABEL with a special class.

Comment: Cool, glad it was helpful ... I just wasn't sure without the </fieldset> if there were any more fields or not. I, too, find myself tempted to abuse HTML elements from time to time. :)

Comment: Well, for radio button groups it is recommended to use the fieldset and legend combo in order for it to be WCAG compliant and work well with screen readers. This is a bit tricky as you cant use wicket:for on a legend with a <wicket:label/> tag inside it so I am not sure how well the screen readers will cope with a label inside the legend like the example show by the original poster as that is the only way to use that combo it seems.

Answer (score 0):

well, the label element itself seems fine - it's the description of the "formInfo" element, so that's no worries. Semantically, however, what's this saying about the `legend` element? It's supposed to be a caption for the entire fieldset....